# Why are pods showing different cpu loads for identical workloads?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

We have the following pods all processing identical workloads but one pod is showing less cpu usage than the others:

[image]

We are deploying the pods on AWS. Pods are deployed across several worker nodes, and each of the worker node types are r5.12xlarge.

Answer (score 1):

This is because even though the vm type is r5.12xlarge, the cpu of each vm won't necessarily be identical on each vm. In the case above there were two different cpus:

Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz

Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8175M CPU @ 2.50GHz

```
POD_NAME=foo
NS=bar
kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME -n $NS -- /bin/cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | uniq
```